# VBoxManage unattended ubuntu live server

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, installation

I try to install the ubuntu-18.04.4-live-server version unattended but it still prompts the *welcome language screen*

[welcome language screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuv58.png)

- I also added the fix from here: [VBoxManage unattended installation of Debian/Ubuntu waits for input](https://superuser.com/questions/1453425/vboxmanage-unattended-installation-of-debian-ubuntu-waits-for-input)
- using iso from https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.4/ubuntu-18.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso
- When using the dekstop version everything works well

```
aux_base_path="$(mktemp -d --tmpdir unattended-install-XXXXX)"
VBoxManage unattended install --auxiliary-base-path "$aux_base_path"/ myvm --install-additions --user=testuser --password=testpw --country=DE --time-zone=EAT --locale=en_US --language=en-US  --hostname=test.local --iso=/home/.../ubuntu_server.iso
sed -i 's/^default vesa.*/default install/' "$aux_base_path"/isolinux-isolinux.cfg
VBoxManage startvm myvm
```

I can see that the `isolinux-isolinux.cfg` is modified in `/tmp/unattended-install-hash` as expected from `vesa` to `install` and that `preseed.cfg` contains the right information.

Answer (score 2):

### Ubunto 20.04

- use [Automated Installs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls)
- patch `isolinux-txt.cfg` so that auto-installs are used
- build `autoinstall.yaml` and make available over http as `user-data` and empty `meta-data` (as per Ubuntu auto install guidelines)

Sample patched `isolinux-txt.cfg`

```
default live
label live
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append   initrd=/casper/initrd quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.2:3003/aux-mcsbeta/ 
label live-nomodeset
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server (safe graphics)
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append   initrd=/casper/initrd quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.2:3003/aux-mcsbeta/ 
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

Sample auto `install.yaml`

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  identity:
    hostname: mcsbeta
    password: $6$0DEwl5R1ymqg6L4N$LjO4rO/NWEkOk9A5aBoOk17m07fXedRdkO.gs6HA6xekTmgv0fpbNRWukUhUP.fVnSP/XD8muFzZVqtTTkBgl.
    realname: ''
    username: mcs
  keyboard:
    layout: us
    variant: ''
  late-commands:
  - 'echo "mcs ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /target/etc/sudoers.d/mcs'
  - chmod 440 /target/etc/sudoers.d/mcs
  - apt-get -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
  - cp /media/cdrom/vboxadditions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run /target/root
  - curtin in-target -t /target -- /bin/bash /root/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run --nox11;
    echo 'vboxadditions installed'
  locale: en_US
  packages:
  - avahi-daemon
  - avahi-autoipd
  - build-essential
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
  storage:
    config:
    - grub_device: true
      id: disk-sda
      path: /dev/sda
      ptable: gpt
      type: disk
      wipe: superblock-recursive
    - device: disk-sda
      flag: bios_grub
      id: partition-0
      number: 1
      size: 1048576
      type: partition
    - device: disk-sda
      id: partition-1
      number: 2
      size: -1
      type: partition
      wipe: superblock
    - fstype: ext4
      id: format-0
      type: format
      volume: partition-1
    - device: format-0
      id: mount-0
      path: /
      type: mount
  version: 1
```

### Ubuntu < 20.04

- use alternate images.  I have not found a way to get casper / Subiquity (live) to work with VBoX unattended. For example [19.10 debian](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.10.1/release/ubuntu-19.10-server-amd64.iso) works, [19.10-live casper/subiquity](https://releases.ubuntu.com/19.10/ubuntu-19.10-live-server-amd64.iso) will always prompt for answers.   I have not found reference to how to get answers.yaml to a Subiquity installer other than building custom ISO.
- I find that `preseed.cfg` needs to be patched.  Newer kernel causes issue on reboot unless patched in late-command.  Plus reliable install of VBoX additions.   Sample late-command:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    echo 'mcs ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/mcs ; \
    in-target chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/mcs ; \
    in-target update-initramfs -c -k 5.3.0-51-generic ; \
    in-target update-grub ; \
    in-target apt-get install -y avahi-daemon avahi-autoipd ; \
    in-target apt-get -y install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) ; \
    in-target /bin/bash /media/cdrom/vboxadditions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run --nox11 ; \
    in-target /bin/bash -c "udevadm constrol --reload-rules" ; \
    in-target /bin/bash -c "udevadm trigger" ; \
    in-target usermod -a -G vboxsf "mcs" ; \
    in-target apt-get install -y openssh-server
```

For my setup I use python code to control getting ISOs,  parameterising command line to VBoXManage,  building and patching configuration.  Completely unattended - but recognising < 20.04 only works with alternate builds that utilise older d-i infrastructure not Subiquity.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this fix. It worked well. I just used `sudo` instead of `vboxsf`. If you want to follow this method, you install Ubuntu using command: `VBoxManage unattended install test2 --user=mcs --password=sometest2 --country=UK --time-zone=UTC --hostname=test2.example.com --iso=/app/ubuntu-scripts/ubuntu-18.04.4-server-amd64.iso --script-template /usr/lib/virtualbox/UnattendedTemplates/ubuntu_preseed.cfg --start-vm=gui` as an example.